# Does $\min_{\textbf{x}} \{f(x)| \|\textbf{x}\|_{2}\leq C \}=\min_{\textbf{x}} \{f(x)| \|\textbf{x}\|_{2}=C \}$ hold, if f convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For some function $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ I've been able to show that it's convex.
It is also not hard to show that the set $V=\{\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n} | \|\textbf{x}\|_{2}\}$ is a convex set. So, now I'm wondering if the following equality holds: $\min_{\textbf{x}} \{f(x)| \|\textbf{x}\|_{2}\leq C \}=\min_{\textbf{x}} \{f(x)| \|\textbf{x}\|_{2}=C \}$, for some constant $C\in \mathbb{R}$.

I've been able to find theorems regarding the attainment of the maximum of convex functions at the boundary of its convex domain (*), but not a similar theorem for the minimum. A source to a theorem which 
enables me to justify the above equality would be a really helpful answer.

Thanks in advance!

-Anil

(*): Theorem 3.1 on page 131 of 'Convexity and Optimization in Rn' by Leonard D. Berkovitz; https://books.google.nl/books?id=f6u9NuiCx7AC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=convex+function+attains+minimum+at+boundary&source=bl&ots=ImDjVwGWi1&sig=cx7DFbLWr20WnTRW36jFt39abiE&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwjcGowsXOAhUGmBoKHUX-B-4Q6AEIZTAJ#v=onepage&q=convex%20function%20attains%20minimum%20at%20boundary&f=false

Comment: You mess up $\min$ and $\max$. The latter is attained on the boundary for convex functions (at an extreme point, in particular).

Comment: Yeah, like I said, the max case I was able to find sources for, the min case I was trying to find out about

Comment: Sorry, I have read only the first half of your post.

Comment: It's okay haha :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, convex functions do not generally attain their minimum at the boundary.  The prototypical example is $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ with
$$
f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2
$$
if we consider $f$ over the unit disk, then it attains its minimum of $0$ at the center, $(0,0)$.

Comment: Well, that was easy :) Thanks bud!

Comment: I would say $f(x)=x^2$ on $[-1,1]$ is the prototypical example.

Comment: @A.G. You're right.  I have only a lack of coffee to blame.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'll buy you one if you're near Eindhoven!

Comment: @Anil my Dutch is quite rusty, but een kopje koffie met poffertjes zou fantastisch zijn :D (and no, I am not near Eindhoven)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Haha, too bad man! It would've been funny if you were at the same university, then I'd definitely buy you some! Some poffertjes would be sweet indeed :D

Comment: @Anil It is not polite to suggest a friend "just coffee" in Eindhoven. It should be at least [beer](https://dutchbeerpages.com/2016/04/07/stadsbrouwerij-eindhoven/)

Comment: @A.G. Haha, it was still morning :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider $V = \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = |x|$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Then for $C > 0$,
$$\min_{\vert x \vert \leq C} f(x) = 0 < C = \min_{\vert x \vert = C} f(x).$$

In a more general setting, just take $f(\mathbf{x}) = \|\mathbf{x}\|_2$ as a counter example.